# Why is my Turret not updating the current enemy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

My problem is that, my turret locates the first enemy, but when it dies, OR, another enemy gets closer, the turret continues to focus on the last position of the first enemy.

The goal is to update the turrets target, to the enemy that is closest to its own transform . At some point I would like to extend that transform, to a player designated area.

```
private Transform target;
float range = 5f;
float distanceToAttackEnemy;
float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
[SerializeField] GameObject turretTower;
[SerializeField] GameObject turretProjektile;
[SerializeField] Transform bulletSpawn;
List<GameObject> listOfEnemies = new List<GameObject>();
GameObject nearestEnemy = null;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    CheckingForClosestEnemyInList();
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == ("Enemy"))
    {
        listOfEnemies.Add(other.gameObject);
    }
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == ("Enemy"))
    {
        listOfEnemies.Remove(other.gameObject);
    }
}

void CheckingForClosestEnemyInList()
{
    
    foreach(GameObject enemy in listOfEnemies)
    {
        
        float distBetweenPlayerAndEnemy = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);

        if (distanceToAttackEnemy < shortestDistance)
        {
            shortestDistance = distanceToAttackEnemy;
            nearestEnemy = enemy;
        }
    }

    if (nearestEnemy != null && shortestDistance <= range)
    {
        var dir = nearestEnemy.transform.position - transform.position;
        var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90;
        turretTower.transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);

    }
    else
    {
        nearestEnemy = null;
    }

}
```

}

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `distBetweenPlayerAndEnemy` is never used in the following comparison. Typo?

Comment: Good god, that was it. Thank you very much.
Now thats a flag for a pit stop... Cheers

Comment: Also, don't forget to reset 'shortestDistance' to 'Mathf.Infinity' on each 'Update()'. Otherwise, you won't be able to acquire a new target until it is closer than the previous enemy died. If that makes sense?